# FIrebaseREcyclerAdapter set for list of values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, denormalization

I have 
'userrecords/userid/recordid' and 'users/userid (full record)/subscriptions/userid(just userid=true to index) ' structure.

Goal is simple: show "all active records related to userid that addded to subscriptions" through FirebaseREcylcerAdapter.

I have the following code now :

```
 DatabaseReference mIdorecords=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    String muid=getUid();
    final DatabaseReference dataRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("userrecords");

    Query keyData = mIdorecords.child(muid).child("subscriptions");

    keyData.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        finalquery=dataRef.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).orderByChild("status").equalTo("Active");
            mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<idorecord, PostViewHolder>(idorecord.class, R.layout.idolist_item,
                    PostViewHolder.class, finalquery)
```

As you see I found out how to get records of only one first particular user specified within 'subscription', but cannot understand how to force to set adapter for each user specified within 'subcription'...
please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **ITERABLE** for this. In example below, I'm getting all user object in database in setting in a list.

```
List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();

    userReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

            for(DataSnapshot child: children)
            {
                User user= child.getValue(User.class);
                list.add(user); 
//here are all user but you can change userReference.child("something") 
//remenber of change User.class for type of you want. String.class, Long.class, etc
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    DatabaseReference mIdorecords=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    String muid=getUid();
    final DatabaseReference dataRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("userrecords");

    Query keyData = mIdorecords.child(muid).child("subscriptions");

    keyData.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
             finalquery=dataRef.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).orderByChild("status").equalTo("Active");    
             finalquery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

             @Override
             public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                 mAdapter.addItem(dataSnapshot.getValue(Record.class))
```

**EDIT:**

I recommend using singleValueEventListener inside the first onChildAdded for efficiency.